# What is wrong with the case when then in my where clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case, where-clause

My requirement: If 'name' AND 'address' are not null, then take values of both in concern. If one of them is null, but the others are given, just "search" for the given.

```
SELECT * from myTable where (1=1) AND (@p_ID is null or [Id] = @p_ID)
AND
    case
    when [Name] IN (SELECT keyValue FROM @p_PersonalData)
        then 
                ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS lines FROM @p_PersonalData) = 0 
                OR ([Address] IN (SELECT dictKey FROM @p_PersonalData))
                AND ([Name] IN (SELECT keyValue FROM p_PersonalData)))
        else
                ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS lines FROM @p_PersonalData) = 0 
                OR ([Address] IN (SELECT dictKey FROM p_PersonalData))
ORDER BY [...]
```

info: It works perfectly without the case. The select-statements and the and´s/or´s are perfectly fine

The issue is, that the sql server management studio red-underlines the equal sign at '= 0' and says he expects AND or THEN, but there IS a 'then'...

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Also, tag with the database you are using.

Comment: `CASE WHEN` doesn't belong in the `WHERE` clause. There is no need to construct conditions there, because the clause already *is* a condition where you can combine subexpressions with `AND`, `OR` and parentheses. Apart from that I have no idea what you are trying to do :-) Follow Gordon's advice and show sample data and expected results. (And yes, tag the DBMS whenever you have a SQL question.)

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have "boolean expressions" as first-class citizens -- you cannot use a boolean expression as a result and there is no (explicit) `TRUE` or `FALSE`. Thus, `CASE WHEN ... THEN <condition> END` is simply not legal, no matter how much sense it makes to us. Rewrite this as something of the form `AND (([Name] IN ... AND ...) OR (NOT ([Name] IN) ... AND ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have conditions in your "then/else" blocks.  Things like this:

```
else
                ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS lines FROM @p_PersonalData) = 0 
                OR ([Address] IN (SELECT dictKey FROM p_PersonalData))
```

are invalid syntax.

Try this, instead.  Note that the case in your WHERE clause is probably very inefficient, and you should consider refactoring this query in a more substantial way.  But this should get you off the ground:

```
SELECT *
from myTable
where (1=1)
  AND (@p_ID is null or [Id] = @p_ID)
  AND case when [Name] IN (SELECT keyValue FROM @p_PersonalData)
           then case when (
                           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS lines FROM @p_PersonalData) = 0 
                           OR
                           ([Address] IN (SELECT dictKey FROM @p_PersonalData))
                           AND
                           ([Name] IN (SELECT keyValue FROM p_PersonalData))
                          )
                      then 1
                      else 0
                end
           else case when (
                           (SELECT COUNT(*) AS lines FROM @p_PersonalData) = 0  OR ([Address] IN (SELECT dictKey FROM p_PersonalData)
                          )
                     then 1
                     else 0
                end
      end = 1
ORDER BY [...]
```